# How can I rotate at custom snap increments?

Tags: snapping

I need to rotate multiple objects in set degree intervals, rather than typing it out for each object, but I would like it to be bigger increments than the default 5 degrees. Is there a way to change the Snapping Transform increments to 22.5/30/45, etc degrees instead of 5?

Comment: I don't think you can, but you can rotate multiple objects simultaneously, using 'Individual Origins', or use Shift-R to repeat the last operation.. would either of those help?

Comment: Shift+R could probably alleviate some of the hassle though I would rather have a snapping feature because then I can rotate in any direction (positive and negative), I would also have to re-do the rotation if I perform any other action though.